# Bootstrap - collapse one <ul> when another <ul> is expanded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

assuming i have this

```
<li>
<a data-toggle="collapse">item 1</a>
</li>
<li>
<ul class="panel-collapse collapse">
<li>sub item 1</li>
<li>sub item 2</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a data-toggle="collapse">item 2</a>
</li>
<li>
<ul class="panel-collapse collapse">
<li>sub item 3</li>
<li>sub item 2</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

In the beginning, all the subitems are collapsed.
Now for example, when i click on item 1 and item 2, subitem 1, 2, 3, 4 will be expanded. This has been IMPLEMENTED.
Now i would like to have subitem 1 and 2 collapsed after i have subitem 3, 4 expanded. How do i archive that? Thanks.

Comment: Using BS3 or what?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the demo**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading " role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#per" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    <strong>Link 1</strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <!--To make by defualt open a any panel put class "in" (without quotes)-->
        <div id="per" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
                <ul class="list-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                 <li class="list-group-item">Link 1</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Link 1</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Link 1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#family" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                   <strong>Link 2</strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="family" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
<ul class="list-group"style=" margin-bottom: 0px;">
                       <li class="list-group-item">Link 2</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Link 2</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Link 2</li>
</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#social" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                     <strong>Link 3</strong>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="social" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
<ul class="list-group" style=" margin-bottom: 0px;">
                      <li class="list-group-item">Link 3</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Link 3</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Link 3</li>
</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when collapsed the css class `collapse` is removed from the list of class of `<ul>/<ul>` element andyou're using jQuery in this project.

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(){
  if($(this:contains('item 2') && $('ul:nth-child(1)').hasClass('collapse'))
   $('ul:nth-child(1)').toggleClass('collapse');
  else if($(this:contains('item 1') && $('ul:nth-child(2)').hasClass('collapse'))   
   $('ul:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('collapse');
});
```